# Using Git on a local network. Cloning from one repository to multiple users, pushing back to remote and being able to see updates from all clones

Tags: git, version-control, repository

I have searched a few posts here (and elsewhere) about using git on a local (lan) network, but either I am missing something, or it's just not working. My scenario is as follows:

- We have a shared network drive of projects (Z:/) on all users PC's
- I want to create a repository within directory 'x' on the shared drive
- Each user (4 of them) need to clone the repository
- Users make changes, commit and push to remote master repository when major changes are made

This seems simple enough, and the general steps on all sites I visited were:

- Create a bare repository on remote machine, in this case
  Z:/SOME_FOLDER
- Create a repository on one local machine, add files, commit and push
  to remote repository in Z:/SOME_FOLDER/ master
- Clone the remote repository at Z:/SOME_FOLDER onto a local PC (let's
  ASSUME PC #2)

This works perfectly, however if I clone the remote repository at Z:/SOME_FOLDER onto pc #3, make some changes, commit and push, when I perform `git status` on pc #2 it is not telling me that there are modified files in the remote repository (although I assume this is only checking the local repository), and there are modified files because PC #3 pushed changes up.

I can run a command like `git fetch file://z:/SOME_FOLDER/ master` and it will update, but my question is this:

How can we have a central repository on Z:/SOME_FOLDER that we can all (4 of us) clone from, commit and push changes, but ALSO see those remote files that have been modified by another user? It is pointless running a fetch command without actually knowing what has been changed.

I am as much of a git novice as they come, so perhaps I have missed a crucial step. Any guidance or links to resources will be much appreciated. Resources I have already looked at:

https://serverfault.com/questions/65104/git-repository-over-lan

http://blog.lazyhacker.com/2010/04/setting-up-git-for-home-network.html

http://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=how%20to%20use%20git%20on%20a%20local%20network%3F&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F2230500%2Fgit-on-a-windows-lan&ei=mxQ6T4eBBIaxhAev_Kz-CQ&usg=AFQjCNEoeBR-kqddSODhHkDlf2qpC8o4tw

**EDIT 2012-02-14 13h30**

By using David's suggestion to use `git pull` rather than `git fetch`, we are able to updated our local repositories with the changes in the master that other users have pushed. The biggest challenge that we are facing at the moment is that if one of us reverts to a previous commit eg: `git reset --hard SOME_HASH` it does not allow us to push it due to the fact that it is a non fast-forward commit.

Even when the person who reverted runs git pull (which I though merges the changes) his files are again updated the latest version on the bare repository. How would we get a local repository that was reverted to a previous commit to be pushed to the remote so we can all be reverted when we run a pull command?

Comment: I don't follow. Why is it pointless running a `fetch` command if you don't know what has been changed? The point of the `fetch` is to get the changes so that you can look at them. (You should use `pull` though.)

Comment: @ David - Perhaps my comment was due to my lack of git knowledge, but at the end of the day, when I fetch (or pull) the remote repository and I run `git status` it does not tell me that file 'X' has been changed, when it has.  Should I have created a bare repository on the remote machine / folder?

Comment: @David - When I used the pull command, it did indeed state that a file had been updated, so thank you for that suggestion.

Comment: The `git` philosophy takes a bit of getting used to, but the basic idea is that everyone works on and in their own repository so everything is fast. They push and pull changes to and from each other as needed/desired/appropriate.

Comment: @David - I guess I need to do more reading, changes are easily updated and pushed, but if one of us resets to a previous revision, there seems to be no way to update the main repository, it keeps saying non fast-forward updates allowed. Even if one of us resets to commit 'X' and performs a pull and then push, it does not reflect on the other repositories, even when a pull command is performed. Goodness, using Github and a local repo is fine, but over a LAN is another story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can we have a central repository on Z:/SOME_FOLDER that we can all (4 of us) clone from, commit and push changes, but ALSO see those remote files that have been modified by another user? It is pointless running a fetch command without actually knowing what has been changed.

The `git fetch` command will get changes in the remote repository and store it in the local repository (in "remote" branches) but not merge them to the current/active branch. If you want to see branches from remote repositories stored your local repository, you can use

```
git branch -a
```

all branches started with `remotes/` are from remote repositories.

To see changes in those branches, you can use `git log` with specifying the branch name, e.g.

```
git log remotes/origin/master
```

and to see files that are changed (compared to your local version), you can use

```
git diff --stat remotes/origin/master
```

Additionally, you can also use `gitk --all` to visually inspect changes in different branches.

The `git status` command only check changes in the active repository (uncommited changes). So it will not compare what you currently have with other branches.

Personally, I usually use `git fetch` without specifying the branch so all branches in the remote repository will be retrieved. Then I use `gitk --all` to visually inspect what changes have been made to the remote repository. After this I can decide what to do with my own changes (rebase, merge, cherry-pick, etc).

Comment: Thank you for that detailed explanation. I will put into practice what you have said and see how that goes. Much appreciated.