# Set up new project repository on windows LAN envirnment

Tags: git, version-control, repository

I was working on a project which I access via git bash on local environment. Now I want to work on another project and I want to set up repository for the new project. My old project repository is on `D:/joy`  location. joy is shared. How do I create new repository and access via other computers of my network?

Comment: Are you asking how you set up a new environment for a project, or do you want to share your current project on other computers?

Comment: set up a new environment for another project already have one.

Comment: The project is already setup and you want to make a copy of it and use it as a a starting point or do you want to copy the project and contribute to that project itself? Or is this a BRAND NEW PROJECT  and you want others to be able to access it?

Comment: I have old project 'vinyas' I want to set up new project 'tukaiexotics' and access remotely form other computers

Comment: But do you want the 'vinyas' files in your 'tukaeioxitcs' files? Or is 'tukaiexotics' seperate?

Comment: 'tukaiexotics' is seperate I do not want vinyas files in tukaiexotics, I do not use github I  use git bash

Comment: I think this is what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274995/using-git-on-a-local-network-cloning-from-one-repository-to-multiple-users-pus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in "[How to use Windows network paths with Git Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20047892/6309)", you can simply use the shared path of the joy (shared) folder to access your repos from other computers:

```
git clone //servername/path/to/repo.git
```

This isusing the [local protocol](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#Local-Protocol), which means there is no authentication or authorization (other than the one imposed by the shared folder permissions by Windows)